# Computing explicit galois actions in Magma

Tags: galois-theory, magma-cas

In the computational algebra system Magma, given an (irreducible) univariate polynomial $f$ (defined over the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$, say), can one compute the action of an element $g$ of the galois group of $f$ on an element $a$ of a splitting field of $f$? If yes, how?

For example, in the framework of the Magma code

```
Q := RationalField();
P<T> := PolynomialRing(Q);
f := T^4 - 10 * T^2 + 1;
Galf := GaloisGroup(f);
L<a> := SplittingField(f);
```

I would like to have Magma compute something like

```
for g in Galf do
    print Evaluate(g,a);
end for;
```

with output as elements of the given splitting field $L$ of $f$. (Here, `Evaluate(g,a)` denotes the action of $g$ on $a$; in Magma, this produces a runtime error.)

### Remarks

1. This question is related to Math Stack Exchange [Question 2822027](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822027/order-of-roots-in-magma-and-or-pari-for-computing-galois-groups).
2. Magma Documentation, [Example H39E5](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/404#4292) appears to explain an approach to this question. See especially the final paragraph of the example. I do not yet understand how to implement it.

Comment: anything unclear ?

Comment: @reuns : Your answer below answers my question. Thank you! I make a few comments to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
      f := x^2+1;
      K<i> := NumberField(f);
      G,r,m := AutomorphismGroup(K);
      m(G.1)(2+i);
      m(G.1^2)(2+i)
```

> ```
>     2-i
>     2+i
> ```

Comment: The application of this answer to the original example is given in another answer. N.B. For an extension of finite fields, say $K/k$, one must specify the base field explicitly, e.g., AutomorphismGroup(K/k). See [Magma documentation](https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/194#1693).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code by @reuns, applied to the original example (additional print statements included for clarity in output):

```
Q := RationalField();
P<T> := PolynomialRing(Q);
f := T^4 - 10 * T^2 + 1;
printf "f = %o\n",f;
printf "(f defined in %o.)\n",Parent(f);
printf "f is irreducible? %o\n",IsIrreducible(f);
L<a> := SplittingField(f);
AutGf,PMapf,TMapf := AutomorphismGroup(L);
printf "\nGenerator(s) of Aut(L/Q):\n%o\n",Generators(AutGf);
print "\nGalois action of each automorphism on a primitive element a of L/Q:";
for g in AutGf do
    printf "g = %-12o : g(a) = %o\n",g,TMapf(g)(a);
end for;
```

(You can run the code for yourself at the [online Magma Calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/).) This outputs

> ```
> f = T^4 - 10*T^2 + 1
> (f defined in Univariate Polynomial Ring in T over Rational Field.)
> f is irreducible? true
>
> Generator(s) of Aut(L/Q):
> {
> (1, 2)(3, 4),
> (1, 3)(2, 4)
> }
>
> Galois action of each automorphism on a primitive element a of L/Q:
> g = Id(AutGf)    : g(a) = a
> g = (1, 2)(3, 4) : g(a) = a^3 - 10*a
> g = (1, 3)(2, 4) : g(a) = -a
> g = (1, 4)(2, 3) : g(a) = -a^3 + 10*a
> ```

If we think of everything as happening inside (a subfield of) the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, and the primitive element as $a = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3}$, then one can check that the final four outputs equal $\pm{}\sqrt{2} \pm{} \sqrt{3}$ -- the four roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$.